# Is there a QM measurement that can distinguish spin in up orientation and in left orientation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Alice creates an electron with its spin |up> or |left>. If Bob measures the spin with an `(up_or_down)` operator he might get result `down` and conclude that since `<down|up> = 0` the electron must have been prepared in `|left>` orientation. 
However, if he measures 'up' this might be a result of `||<up|up>||=1` or `||<up|left>||=1/2`. Similar logic applies to `(left_or_right)` measurement.

Is there a way for Bob to apply measurements to more reliably distinguish `|up>` and `|left>`? This can be a sequence of measurements. Can he apply up-right magnetic field, transform spin to up-left and measure the change in energy to distinguish between `|up>` and `|left>`? What is the best sequence of measurements for Bob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a basis where $|up\rangle$ and $|down\rangle$ are represented by $\pmatrix{1\cr0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\cr1}$.

If $|left\rangle=|up\rangle+|down\rangle$ (I am not normalizing) then you seem to be asking for a Hermitian matrix with $\pmatrix{1\cr0}$ and $\pmatrix{1\cr1}$ as eigenvectors.

It's easy to check that there is no such matrix.